# Definite Integral involving matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices, derivatives

We have a definite integral of the form given below

> $ f(t) = \int_0^1 e^{\alpha X(t)} \frac{dX(t)}{dt} e^{(1-\alpha) X(t)}\,d\alpha \tag 1$

**Given Data in the question**

1. $X(t)$ is a skew-symmetric matrix of dimension $ 3 \times 3$;
2. $f(t)$ is a  $ 3 \times 3$ matrix.

Question

Can we evaluate $f(t)$ given general skew-symmetric $X(t)$? I am unable to tackle it by normal rules. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking for the indefinite integral of your integrand? Or the derivative of $f(t)$? Or the integral of $f(t)$?

Comment: Just the f(t) after evaluation of integral on RHS